# Как определить стиль речи

Tags: грамотная-речь

Нужно ли на форуме соблюдать этикет речи? Наверное, это  необходимо, но сначала надо понять, что такое речевой этикет в условиях  общения  "вопрос-ответ".

И для начала мне хотелось бы определить, **к какому стилю речи относятся, например, следующие выражения:** "это попахивает софизмом, вы умудрились придраться, развели тут обычную демагогию".

**Можно ли дать оценку  не словам, которые могут быть нейтральными, а именно выражениям?** Это же не грубое просторечие, а что это?

Когда и к кому удобно так обращаться? Нормально ли на нашем ресурсе так комментировать ответ участника на поставленный вами вопрос?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы назвал это резкой критикой с использованием уничижительных эпитетов и переходом на личность оппонента (автора). Такое встречается при обращении к политическому противнику на каких-нибудь политических дебатах и в такой ситуации свидетельствует о несдержанности говорящего, неумении ограничить предмет критики её направленностью на содержание (здесь она направлена на автора: "вы умудрились и развели"). Более уместна такая риторика в отношении подчинённого: например, строгого и ответственного редактора не устраивает представленная к публикации статья (подчинённый ему журналист написал явно не то, что от него ожидалось и т.п.); как ответственное лицо он может позволить себе критику личных качеств сотрудника и оценку его действий.

Comment: Наверное, это агрессивная риторика, а стиль эклетичный, идет в ход всё, что имеет негативную окраску. Думаю, что участникам надо знакомиться с правилами форума, а модераторам строже следить за их выполнением..

Answer (score 3):

Если только стиль речи, то разговорный. Что касается нормативности такого тона на форуме, конечно,он нежелательный. Здесь чувствуется явная агрессия, раздраженность, недовольство.

Comment: Серж, а какие здесь особенности лексики разговорного стиля? Разговорный стиль - это стиль упрощенный, сниженный по отношению к общелитературной речи. Например, в разговорном стиле частотны слова, выражающие  отрицательную оценку:  "жигуль", "бормотуха", "междусобойчик" .  Для разговорного стиля характерно употребление фразеологизмов, например: с ножом к горлу пристать, уши вянут, переливать из пустого в порожнее. В речи широко используется лексика бытового содержания, отсутствуют книжные слова с абстрактным значением. Но как-то всё не это.

Comment: Вера, ну ведь такие слова,как: ''умудрились'', ''попахивает'', ''развели'' имеют разговорный оттенок.

Comment: Да, слова разговорные, оценочные, с дополнительным значением, но они перемешаны с книжными. Скорее всего, это именно особая риторика с разными стилями.

Answer (score 2):

А если это и правда софизм и демагогия... Что делать-с, приходится называть вещи своими именами.

Comment: Вот этого как раз не надо делать, а нужно просто отвечать на вопросы. И оценивать нужно не людей, а ответы, причем в такой примерно форме: "Мне кажется, что вы ошибаетесь, потому что..." И далее обоснование своего мнения. А обличать софистов и демагогов следует на других площадках - реальных или виртуальных.